# how to manage gem path in development with team?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, gemfile

i've been having a problem working in a project with my team, and i want to know how you manage situations like this.

We're working in the same project, and the project has gems made by us, and we're working on those gems as well.

So our gemfile looks like:

```
# Person 1
gem "my_gem", '1.1', :path => '/Users/person1/apps/my_gem/'

# Person 2
gem "my_gem", '1.1', :path => '/Users/person2/apps/my_gem/'

# Person 3
gem "my_gem", '1.1', :path => '/Users/person3/apps/my_gem/'
```

The problem is that when we push to our remote with Git, we're having conflicts everytime (sounds logic). I tried to use environment variables with dotenv gem, doing something like:

```
# Person x
gem "my_gem", '1.1', :path => ENV["MY_PATH"]
```

I tried a lot, differents ways, using as reference many stackoverflow's posts... but doesn't work.

Comment: why doesn't the `ENV` approach work?

Comment: I think if we set up ENVs through our terminal it will work just fine, that is our plan b. I tried using dotenv gem with bad results, gemfile is readed before load dotenv, so doesn't recognize .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also agree on a relative path-structure? You could do something like

```
gem "my_gem", :path => '../../apps/my_gem/'
```

Personally I always use the `path` to develop against a gem, locally, but I always push the git reference to my collegues (because that also means that the code I am developing against --the gem, is released -- at least pushed to the repo).

```
gem "my_gem", git: 'git@github.com:username/my_gem.git'
```

And in the `Gemfile.lock` (which we also push to repository) we see the revision so that when collegues install, or upon deploy we get the same version.

Comment: Thank you @nathanvda, finally we decide to use relative paths and it works as a charm :) .

Answer (score 3):

I have 2 solutions for you:

#### 1. Each gem has its own git repository.

You can give each gem a separate git repository, and your `Gemfile` will look like:

```
# Assuming private Github
# and your private keys are setup correctly on Github.
gem 'my_gem', '1.1', git: 'git@github.com:username/my_gem.git'
```

#### 2. Use `__dir__`.

[`Kernel.__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) returns the absolute directory of file invoking this method. This means, we can always get the base directory regardless of user.

Assuming`Gemfile` is located at `/Users/person1/apps/my_app/Gemfile`. Then `__dir__` will return `/Users/person1/apps/my_app`.

```
gem "my_gem", '1.1', path: File.join(__dir__, '..', 'my_gem')
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron ! first one looks a good idea, but i would prefer the second one, so i will try as soon as possible and i tell you how it goes

Comment: FYI Per @nathanvda's solution, I just tested that relative path works as well.